# Pagination of non-table data in Angular 8 with Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm a total beginner in Angular Development and I've only today installed Angular 8. I'm trying to paginate data returned from a webservice and only display a certain number per page.

All of the questions and tutorials I can find online are to do with paginating table data, however my application displays its data on a grid of 3*X Bootstrap Cards with no table, and I was hoping I could count these cards perhaps during their rendering in my ngFor and display, say, 9 per page, as the search could return quite a large number of objects and displaying all of them on one page seems unfriendly to my users. Any possible solutions and advise is appreciated.

Comment: Use Material Table, it's simple and has all bells and whistles.

Comment: what you want is of course doable, but you need to provide some code with what you've tried, maybe a stackblitz or something